# Optimizing A List of athlete's competitions with LINQ query or similar approach

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to construct a function that will optimize the outcome for athletes competing in competitions.  Let's say I have a class of Athlete:

```
public class Athlete
{
    public int ID {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RunningAbility { get; set; }
    public int SwimmingAbility { get; set; }

    public readonly List<Attempt> { get; set; }
}
```

Each athlete makes 2 attempts in the competition.  They can compete in swimming two times, running two times, or can do one of each.  The only stipulation is that the # of runners and swimmers has to be equal; so if there were 3 athletes there needs to be 6 attempts - 3 running and 3 swimming.

The Attempt class looks like this:

```
public class Attempt
{
    public string AthleteID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make a list of Attempt that has the best possible scenario.

```
public void Main(){
    var people = new List<Athlete>() {
        new Athlete()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            RunningAbility = 10,
            SwimmingAbility = 10
        },
        new Athlete()
        {
            Name = "Joe",
            RunningAbility = 8,
            SwimmingAbility = 2
        },
        new Athlete()
        {
            Name = "Sue",
            RunningAbility = 3,
            SwimmingAbility = 7
        },
    };

    var attempts = GetBestPossible(people);
}

private List<Attempt> GetBestPossible(List<People> people)
{
    var attempts = new List<Attempt>();
    //Each Person must compete twice and can either use both attempts in same event or one in each event
    //The entire team Must have equal attempts for running and swimming - i.e. 3 attempt swimming and 3 attempts running in this case.
    //How would I make a linq query or comparable solution on people that would give me a 
    //list of attempts with the max ability utilized for both events?
    //Expected outcome for attempts list would be 
    //Name  Event
    //Bob   Running
    //Bob   Swimming
    //Joe   Running
    //Joe   Running
    //Sue   Swimming
    //Sue   Swimming

    //Meets criteria of having each Person attempt twice 
    //and equal attempts in both events with MAX ability

    return attempts;
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with Linq or if it's not possible with the given details?  I'm not sure where to start on this so any help is GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT: Added a `List<Attempt>` property to my `Person` class,  I am still not sure how I can solve my issue but I am thinking I need to write a function that loops through every possible outcome per Athlete instance and then tallies and somehow determines which outcome one is the best for both events.

Comment: Have you devised the algorithm that selects the best chances?

Comment: No that is what I'm trying to figure out and was hoping that I could do so with LINQ but does not have to be.  I just don't know where to start.

Comment: How about adding a `List<Attempt>` in the `Athlete` class as a start?

Comment: @JQSOFT I have omitted a lot to try and simplify my question but I'm not sure how adding the `List<Attempt>` to the `Athlete` class will solve my issue - could you explain why this would be of use?  In the end I don't necessarily need to know Person.Attempts rather just a flat output of the person's name and which event to compete.  Would the `List<Attempt>` as a property of the `Athlete` be used to excecute my intended algorithm?

Comment: Just a suggestion to have your objects connected so the LINQ queries will be easier. However, you know your needs better. Also, There is something unclear (at least for me)  in the second paragraph, how the three athletes example should have three running and three swimming attempts and they have a choice to compete one swimming and one running? So, you need to elaborate a little bit more if you don't mind.

Comment: @JQSOFT I have added some more detail and the `List<Attempt>` to my `Athlete` class.  The part in the second paragraph is that each must compete twice - either both in swimming or both in running or one in each.  And the other rule is that for all of the athletes attempts combined the swimming attempts must equal the running attempts.  So there couldn't be 4 swimmers and 2 runners.  In this example there are 3 athletes so there would need to be 6 attempts - 3 run, 3 swim.  Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that hopefully will help in a way or another to solve the problem.

You have two games/competitions, Let's create an `enum` for them:

```cs
//...
public enum Competitions { Running, Swimming }
//...
```

The `Attempt` class, max. two instances of this object for each `Athlete` regardless of the competitions types.

```cs
//...
public class Attempt
{
    public Competitions Competition { get; set; } 
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
//...
```

The `Athlete` class:

```cs
//...
public class Athlete
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public readonly List<Attempt> Attempts = new List<Attempt>();

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
//...
```

And one more class that will be a report/statistics/status (you name it) entry for each athlete.

```cs
//...
public class Statistics
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Running { get; set; }
    public int Swimming { get; set; }
    public int TotalScore { get => Running + Swimming; }
    public int RunningRank { get; set; }
    public int SwimmingRank { get; set; }
    public int GeneralRank { get; set; }
}
//...
```

In your implementation, you have a `List<Athlete>` filled with some entries, for example:

```cs
//...
List<Athlete> Athletes = new List<Athlete>();

private void CreateList()
{
    Athletes.Clear();

    var jim = new Athlete { Name = "Jim" };
    jim.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Swimming, Score = 1 });
    jim.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Swimming, Score = 2 });

    var joe = new Athlete { Name = "Joe" };
    joe.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 7 });
    joe.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Swimming, Score = 2 });

    var sue = new Athlete { Name = "Sue" };
    sue.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 3 });
    sue.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Swimming, Score = 7 });

    var bob = new Athlete { Name = "Bob" };
    bob.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 10 });
    bob.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Swimming, Score = 10 });

    var ben = new Athlete { Name = "Ben" };
    ben.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 5 });

    var sam = new Athlete { Name = "Sam" };
    sam.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 6 });
    sam.Attempts.Add(new Attempt { Competition = Competitions.Running, Score = 4 });

    Athletes.AddRange(new[] { jim, joe, sue, bob, ben, sam });
}
//...
```

Now let's create a statistics or report for each member ***where*** the sum of their running and swimming attempts are equal.

```cs
//...
private IEnumerable<Statistics> CreateStatistics()
{
    var ath = Athletes.Where(x => x.Attempts.Count() == 2
    && x.Attempts.First().Competition != x.Attempts.Last().Competition);

    var abi = (from a in ath
                select new Statistics
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Running = a.Attempts
                    .First(r => r.Competition == Competitions.Running).Score,
                    Swimming = a.Attempts
                    .First(s => s.Competition == Competitions.Swimming).Score,
                }).ToList();

    foreach (var a in abi)
    {
        a.RunningRank = 1 + abi.Select(r => r.Running).OrderByDescending(r => r)
            .ToList().IndexOf(a.Running);

        a.SwimmingRank = 1 + abi.Select(s => s.Swimming).OrderByDescending(s => s)
            .ToList().IndexOf(a.Swimming);

        a.GeneralRank = 1 + abi.Select(t => t.TotalScore).OrderByDescending(t => t)
            .ToList().IndexOf(a.TotalScore);
    }

    return abi;
}
//...
```

The outcome is:

[image: SOQ60819266]

As you can see, the query selected three members only from the list and created a statistics entry for each that shows their scores and calculates their ranks for each game, as well as the general or overall rank.

Good luck.

Comment: I have played around with this and it helps me a lot.  I appreciate the guidance.  I did some numbers and learned a bit about permutations and combinations as well and found that having three outcomes for 20 positions results in roughly 3^20 combinations - roughly 3.5 billion!  I have to look at some refining techniques - as in this example I would probably never want Joe to compete in swimming or Sue in running so I think I can do some "thinking" and get this 3.5 billion whittled down to a managable number.  Thanks Again!

Comment: @Ben Most welcome mate. Glad to solve this one because It overheated my brain. I'll call it **Covid 19 Olympics** :)